# Sum 2 hashes attributes with the same key

Tags: ruby, hash, attributes, sum

I have 2 hashes, for example:

```
{'a' => 30, 'b' => 14}
{'a' => 4, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 7}
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are objects. How can I sum those hashes' keys to get a new hash like:

```
{'a' => 34, 'b' => 37, 'c' => 7}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
a_hash = {'a' => 30, 'b' => 14}
b_hash = {'a' => 4, 'b' => 23, 'c' => 7}

a_hash.merge(b_hash){ |k, a_value, b_value| a_value + b_value }
=> {"a"=>34, "b"=>37, "c"=>7}

b_hash.merge(a_hash){ |k, b_value, a_value| a_value + b_value }
=> {"a"=>34, "b"=>37, "c"=>7}
```

Comment: How to add only specific keys?

Comment: @NARENPUSHPARAJU you can use an `if` statement in the block. Something like: `if foo; a+b; else; a; end`

Answer (score 6):

If some one looking to add more than 2 hashes, use this

```
#sample array with any number of hashes
sample_arr =  [{:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>8, :d=>20, :e=>5},
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>4, :d=>10, :e=>5, :r=>7},
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>4, :d=>10},
{:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>8, :d=>20, :e=>5},
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>4, :d=>10, :e=>5, :r=>7},
{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>4, :d=>10}]

sample_arr.inject { |acc, next_obj| acc.merge(next_obj) { |key,arg1,arg2| arg1+arg2 } }
# => {:a=>8, :b=>16, :c=>32, :d=>80, :e=>20, :r=>14}
```

In case of heterogeneous hash (containing both String and Number). For adding only integers.

```
@resultant_visit_hash = arr.inject { |acc, next_obj| acc.merge(next_obj) { |key,arg1,arg2| arg1+arg2 if (arg1.class == Integer && arg2.class == Integer) } }
```

Code is self explanatory.