# add up values from 2 arrays based on duplicate values of the other one

Tags: ruby, arrays

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453511/ruby-group-hashes-by-keys-and-sum-the-values) However I'd like to know how I can add up/group the numbers from one array based on the duplicate values of another array.

```
test_names = ["TEST1", "TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "TEST2", "TEST4", "TEST4", "TEST4"]
numbers = ["5", "4", "3", "2", "9", "7", "6", "1"]
```

The ideal result I'd like to get is a hash or an array with:

```
{"TEST1" => 9, "TEST2" => 12, "TEST3" => 2, "TEST4" => 14}
```

Comment: Will the arrays be symmetrical such that they can be "zipped"?

Comment: yes, they will be symmetrical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
my_hash = Hash.new(0)
test_names.each_with_index {|name, index| my_hash[name] += numbers[index].to_i}
my_hash
#=> {"TEST1"=>9, "TEST2"=>12, "TEST3"=>2, "TEST4"=>14}
```

Comment: in my real code the numbers are floats so after they all add up in my_hash[name] I get a long list of digits after the floating point. 
Is there a way to nicely add .round(3) somewhere in the same line of code or do I have to again iterate over the hash and round_up each number individually?

Comment: sure, that's pretty basic, you can see the part where you're adding the numbers, so instead of just adding `numbers[index].to_i` just add `numbers[index].to_f.round(3)` so that they stay floats and you round them. You should be able to see that from the code.

Comment: yeah, I get that, but I was talking about the final result, so even if I do numbers[index].round(3) for each number the final result can still have a lot of digits after the floating point.
I want my_hash[name] to be rounded to 3

Comment: No, it is impossible to add two numbers that have 3 decimal places together and get a number with 4 decimal places.

Comment: However, the answer doing it that way would have a larger inaccuracy than just looping afterwards and rounding which is what I would do. (the inaccuracy `5*10^-4*n > 5*10^-4` where n is the number of terms in the summation)

Answer (score 2):

Another way I found you can do:

```
test_names.zip(numbers).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {
    |arr, hsh| hsh[arr[0]] += arr[1].to_i }
```

Comment: I suggest you disambiguate (a useful word, I suppose, but I hate it) `arr` and write `...|(name,nbr),hsh| hsh[name] += nbr.to_i` }.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I was unaware that you could unpack like that.  But that looks neater, good tip.

Answer (score 1):

I wish to follow @squidguy's example and use [Enumerable#zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), but with a different twist:

```
{}.tap { |h| test_names.zip(numbers.map(&:to_i)) { |a|
  h.update([a].to_h) { |_,o,n| o+n } } } 
  #=> {"TEST1"=>9, "TEST2"=>12, "TEST3"=>2, "TEST4"=>14}
```

- [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) is here just a substitute for [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) or for having `h={}` initially and a last line with just `h`.
- I'm using the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that takes a block for determining the merged value for each key that is present in both the original hash (`h`) and the hash being merged (`[a].to_h`). There are three block variables, the shared key (which we don't use here, so I've replaced it with the placeholder `_`), and the values for that key for the original hash (`o`) and for the hash being merged (`n`).