# Nested Hash sum

Tags: ruby, hash

I've this hash

```
{
    19132=>{
        :occurences=>34,
        :name=>"bar"
    },
    19133=>{
        :occurences=>19,
        :name=>"foo"
    }
}
```

I would like to find the addition of occurrences (34+19) in a new key (why not `total`) on each key (19132 and 19133).

I've something like:

```
my_hash = {19132=>{:occurences=>34, :name=>"bar"}, 19133=>{:occurences=>19, :name=>"foo"}}
my_hash.values.inject{|memo, el| memo.merge(el){|k, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v if k.is_a?(Numeric)}}
```

I've found some help [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453511/ruby-group-hashes-by-keys-and-sum-the-values) but I'm stuck with the merge. I don't even know if this method can solve my problem.

Comment: Can you post your desired output?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but the total could be computed without reference to the key `:occurrences` (note two r's): `hash.values.map(&:values).flatten.reduce(0) { |tot, v| tot + v.to_i } #=> 53`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sum = h.values.inject(0) {|sum, h| sum + h[:occurences] }
# => 53 
h.map {|k, v| v[:total] = sum; [k,v]}.to_h
# => { 19132=>{:occurences=>34, :name=>"bar", :total=>53},
#      19133=>{:occurences=>19, :name=>"foo", :total=>53} }
```

Comment: You can avoid the creation of a temporary array by replacing [Hash#values](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values) with the enumerator [Hash#each_value](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-each_value).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, But wouldn't that calculate the sum, for each value in the Hash ?

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking, but I'm not suggesting that you change the block, which only references `:occurrences`.  Note that `Enumerator.included_modules.first #=> Enumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

First, go through all the inner hashes and calculate the total:

`total = h.values.inject(0) { |total, hash| total + hash[:ocurrences] }`

And then, add the total to the inner hashes:

`h.keys.each{|k| h[k][:total] = total}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried achieving it in two steps: find total and merge total.

```
hash = {19132=>{:occurences=>34, :name=>"bar"}, 19133=>{:occurences=>19, :name=>"foo"}}

total = hash.collect(&:first).sum
# => 38265

hash.each{|h| h[1].merge!({"total" => total})}
# => {19132=>{:occurences=>34, :name=>"bar", "total"=>38265}, 19133=>{:occurences=>19, :name=>"foo", "total"=>38265}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
tot = h.each_value.reduce(0) { |t, g| t + g[:occurrences] }
h.merge(h) { |*_,g| g.merge("total"=>tot) }
  # => {19132=>{:occurrences=>34, :name=>"bar", "total"=>53},
  #     19133=>{:occurrences=>19, :name=>"foo", "total"=>53}}
```

This does not mutate the original hash:

```
h #=> {19132=>{:occurrences=>34, :name=>"bar"},
  #    19133=>{:occurrences=>19, :name=>"foo"}}
```

If you wish to change `h` in place:

```
h.merge!(h) { |*_,g| g.merge!("total"=>tot) }
```

works, but:

```
h.each_value { |g| g["total"] = tot }
```

is better.