# Ruby aggregate selective values within a collection of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes with the keys being countries and the values being number of days.

I would like to aggregate over the hashes and sum the values for the countries that are the same.

the array could look like this `countries = [{"Country"=>"Brazil", "Duration"=>731/1 days}, {"Country"=>"Brazil", "Duration"=>365/1 days}]`

I would like this to return something on the lines of: `[{"Country" => "Brazil", "Duration"=>1096/1 days}]`

I tried the other questions on SO [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453511/group-hashes-by-keys-and-sum-the-values)

```
countries.inject{|new_h, old_h| new_h.merge(old_h) {|_, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v}}
```

Produces `{"Country"=>"BrazilBrazil", "Duration"=>1096/1 days}`

Is there a way to selectively only merge specific values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may update your code as follows:

```
countries.inject do |new_h, old_h| 
    new_h.merge(old_h) do |k, old_v, new_v|
        if k=="Country" then old_v else old_v + new_v end
    end 
end
#  => {"Country"=>"Brazil", "Duration"=>1096}
```

where you basically use the `k` (for *key*) argument to switch among different merging policies.

Answer (score 4):

This uses the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that creates a creates an empty hash with a default value (here `0`). For a hash `h` created that way, `h[k]` returns the default value if the hash does not have a key `k`. The hash is not modified.

```
countries = [{"Country"=>"Brazil",    "Duration"=>"731/1 days"},
             {"Country"=>"Argentina", "Duration"=>"123/1 days"},
             {"Country"=>"Brazil",    "Duration"=>"240/1 days"},
             {"Country"=>"Argentina", "Duration"=>"260/1 days"}]

countries.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|g,h| h[g["Country"]] += g["Duration"].to_i }.
  map { |k,v| { "Country"=>k, "Duration"=>"#{v}/1 days" } }
    #=> [{"Country"=>"Brazil",    "Duration"=>"971/1 days"},
    #    {"Country"=>"Argentina", "Duration"=>"383/1 days"}]
```

The first hash passed to the block and assigned to the block variable `g`.

```
g = {"Country"=>"Brazil", "Duration"=>"731/1 days"}
```

At this time `h #=> {}`. We then compute

```
h[g["Country"]] += g["Duration"].to_i
  #=> h["Brazil"] += "971/1 days".to_i
  #=> h["Brazil"] = h["Brazil"] + 971
  #=> h["Brazil"] = 0 + 971 # h["Brazil"]
```

See [String#to_i](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) for an explanation of why `"971/1 days".to_i` returns `971`.

`h["Brazil"]` on the right of the equality returns the default value of `0` because `h` does not (yet) have a key `"Brazil"`. Note that `h["Brazil"]` on the right is syntactic sugar for `h.[]("Brazil")`, whereas on the left it is syntactic sugar for `h.[]=(h["Brazil"] + 97)`. It is [Hash#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) that returns the default value when the hash does not have the given key. The remaining steps are similar.

Comment: `Hash.new(0)` will convert the duration to seconds. You may want to try do `Hash.new(0.days)` and then inside the map block you can do `"Duration" => v`

Comment: @TheLegend, thanks for the suggestion. I don't know Rails so I gave a pure-Ruby solution.