# How to extract information from hashes of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I trying to get a new hashes of array, it will list every :name in the hashes of array(e) which was provided only once, and the value should be the total score which should be the sum of scores under same :name in the array(e).

```
e = [
{:name => "Oyster", :score => 1000},
{:name => "Tiger", :score => 2000},
{:name => "Frog", :score => 2300},
{:name => "Frog", :score => 1220},
{:name => "Tiger", :score => 200},
{:name => "Frog", :score => 1000},
{:name => "Oyster", :score => 2000},
{:name => "Frog", :score => 300},
{:name => "Monkey", :score => 500},
{:name => "Oyster", :score => 3300}
]
```

I searched google for 「hash array ruby」, and ruby's documentation but haven't got any very useful information yet.

I tried to solve this problem by doing the following:

```
f = e.map{|t|t[:name]}.uniq
n = Hash[f.map{|v|[v,0]}]
result = n.map{|key, value|e.map{|t| if key == t[:name]; n[key] += t[:score].to_i end}}
```

but the result is

```
[[1000, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 3000, nil, nil, 6300], [nil, 2000, nil, nil, 2200, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, 2300, 3520, nil, 4520, nil, 4820, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 500, nil]]
```

it's totally different from my expectation.
if we want to reach the very neat result what should we do.

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453511/group-hashes-by-keys-and-sum-the-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group_by` to group the hashes by `:name` and then sum `:score:` values using `reduce` with `merge`, like this:

```
e.group_by { |h| h[:name] }.map do |_, v| 
  v.reduce do |acc, h| 
    acc.merge(h) { |k, ov, nv| k == :name ? ov : ov + nv }
  end
end

#=> [{:name=>"Oyster", :score=>6300}, {:name=>"Tiger", :score=>2200}, {:name=>"Frog", :score=>4820}, {:name=>"Monkey", :score=>500}]
```

Explanation:

- `group_by { |h| h[:name] }` groups all hashes by name, which yields something like this:

  ```
  {
    "Oyster"=>[
      {:name=>"Oyster", :score=>1000},
      {:name=>"Oyster", :score=>2000},
      {:name=>"Oyster", :score=>3300}
    ],
    "Tiger"=>[...]
  }
  ```
- `.map` iterates the resulting hash, ignoring the grouping key (`_` variable) and uses only the value (`v` variable, which contains the array of grouped hashes) to sum the scores of each hash (see next step).
- `reduce` sums the values of `score` by merging all hashes from the array together (`acc` is the *accumulated* value/hash and `h` is the current value/hash being iterated). Notice that `merge` is used with a block so, instead of replacing the value of a duplicated key (like a `merge` without a block), it will replace its values using the code within the block where:

  - `k` is the current key of the hash being merged.
  - `ov` is the old value (i.e. value of the `acc` hash) for the given key.
  - `nv` is the new value (i.e. value of the `h` hash) for the given key.

So, after grouping the hashes by `name`, it iterates each group of hashes and merges them into one, evaluating first if the current key is `:name` and, if it does, it keeps the old value (e.g. `"Oyster"`), otherwise (e.g. `:score`) it will sum the old vale with the new value and replace the value of `score` with that result, *accumulating* the value on each iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is my first question on StackOverflow and I not expected a sharp answer like this. For me, Your solution is perfect. 

Answer (score 0):

I know this post already has an accepted answer, but if you dont want the result to be an array of hashes and just want the given score for the given name you could:

```
e.inject({}) do |totals, current| 
  totals[current[:name]] = (totals[current[:name]] || 0) + current[:score] 
  totals
end

#=> {"Oyster"=>6300, "Tiger"=>2200, "Frog"=>4820, "Monkey"=>500}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried your solution, it's very neat. It provided me a new way to solve this problem. I am so appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: @JunMeng No Problem

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
new_array = []
e.each{|h| new_array << { h[:name] => h[:score]} }
new_array.inject{|name, score| name.merge( score ){|k, old_v, new_v| old_v + new_v}}


#=> {"Oyster"=>6300, "Tiger"=>2200, "Frog"=>4820, "Monkey"=>500}
```

Comment: 非常感谢，刚开始自学ruby能收到不同的答案好幸福。Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a hash created using [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html) with a default value of zero (sometimes called a *counting hash*), then convert the hash to an array of hashes. See the doc for details.

```
e.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:name]] += g[:score] }.
  map { |k,v| { name: k, score: v } }
  #=> [{:name=>"Oyster", :score=>6300},
  #    {:name=>"Tiger",  :score=>2200},
  #    {:name=>"Frog",   :score=>4820},
  #    {:name=>"Monkey", :score=>500}]
```

Comment: I really like this block.  Many thanks to you and the community.