# Merge or sum 2 arrays on "keys" in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sum

This is the array version of: [Sum 2 hashes attributes with the same key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091487/sum-2-hashes-attributes-with-the-same-key)

I have 2 arrays, for example:

```
a = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]
b = [[1,50],[3,70]]
```

How can i sum each on the first value (if it exists) to get:

```
c = [[1,60],[2,20],[3,100]]
```

Comment: I've tried using Array#assoc but I haven been able to get it right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do it thusly:

```
(a + b).group_by(&:first).map { |k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
```

First you put the arrays together with `+` since you don't care about `a` and `b`, you just care about their elements. Then the [`group_by`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) partitions the combined array by the first element so that the inner arrays can easily be worked with. Then you just have to pull out the second (or last) elements of the inner arrays with [`v.map(&:last)`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) and sum them with [`inject(:+)`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

For example:

```
>> a = [[1,10],[2,20],[3,30]]
>> b = [[1,50],[3,70]]
>> (a + b).group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, v.map(&:last).inject(:+)] }
=> [[1, 60], [2, 20], [3, 100]]
```

Comment: Nice one liner, plus a good explanation of how it works, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do it *the hash way*:

```
Hash[a].merge(Hash[b]){|k,a,b|a+b}.to_a
```

Comment: In this particular case `Hash[*a.flatten]` is the same thing as `Hash[a]`, only the latter is faster I presume.

Comment: Of course, I didn't think of casting them into hashes, gracias!

Comment: I used it in two hashes: `hash1.merge(hash2){|k, a, b| a + b }`. Thank you.